# Showing a loading page in a google chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have searched high and low for this but whatever i do this simply does not seem to work. I have a google chrome extension which send an XHR request using a background.js file. Now my requirement is that i need to show a small loading icon while the xhr request is proceeding. Are there any tutorials out there which explains how to do this. I have tried an iframe but it looks ugly when it expands as the entire popup.html expands. Is jquery my only option here because that would mean adding a lot of size to my current project just for a simple animation.

Comment: Not at all. Vanilla JavaScript is more than capable of displaying a simple loading icon. No need for JQuery.

Comment: Any ideas on how to do this other than using an iframe or is that my only option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define two functions showIcon and hideIcon.

```
 function showIcon() {
   document.getElementById('loading').style.display ='block';
 } 

 function hideIcon() {
   document.getElementById('loading').style.display ='none';
 }
```

You execute showIcon when making the xhr request and then call hideIcon when xhr returns.

//html

```
<div id="loading">Loading</div>
```

//css

```
#loading{

text-indent:-9999px
background-image:url('loading.gif');
display:none;

}
```

Comment: I have to add the icon using the img tag and set its width and height to 0 orginally right

Comment: No. Its much easier to set a background-image using css as I show above. You can also specify image size with css.

Comment: Oh okay.Completely missed that.